# How to reference a dynamic workbook name

Tags: excel, vba

This seems to be a simple issue but I can't find a solution that works.
Basically, in my code right now the workbook is hardcoded as its name.

However, I want to be able to change the name depending on what the user inputs on a specific cell; instead of Workbooks("OH Detail v13"), it would be Workbooks("Whatever is in Cell C2 of Sheet FilePath")

```
    Dim openbook As Workbook
    Dim xpath As String, xfile As String, xext As String

       xpath = Sheets("FilePath").Range("C2").Value 'This is where there is the workbook name I want to be dynamic
       xfile = "\" & Sheets("FilePath").Range("C3").Value
       xext = ".xlsx"

    Set openbook = Workbooks.Open(xpath & xfile & xext) 'This works
   `This is where I want the dynamic Workbook name:

    Workbooks("OH Detail v13").Sheets("Invoices").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Invoices").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
    Selection.Copy 'Copied into the workbook where the code is
    Workbooks("OH Details_v2").Sheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

I have tried adding:

```
    Dim wsOG As Workbook
    Set wsOG = Workbooks(xpath)

    wsOG.Sheets("Invoices").Select
```

And it gives me error: Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Slightly confused, are you attempting to first open an existing file? Or to create a new file with a given name? With a "dynamic" workbook name it would either have to exist or to be created.

Comment: Note that tags Excel VBA do not belong in the descriptive title. I have removed them.

Comment: @AndyG I am able to open the existing file, the first part of the code works. However, for the rest of the code instead of writing Workbooks("Oh Detail v13") every time I want the name to be the same as the the value in "xpath"

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd try and avoid using `.Select` if you can - the best way to do it would be to ignore `ActiveSheet` and `Dim ws As Worksheet` etc. Your question name is confusing. Try changing it to "How to reference a dynamic workbook name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
XPath = Sheets("FilePath").Range("C2").Value 'This is where there is the workbook name I want to be dynamic
xfile = Sheets("FilePath").Range("C3").Value
xext = ".xlsx"

'Open a workbook
Set wsOG = Workbooks.Open(XPath & "\" & xfile & xext, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True) 'Parameters are optional

'Set a workbook which is already open
Set wsOG = Workbooks(xfile & xext)
```

Note that I've deleted the "\" from your xfile variable because it wouldn't work when you want to Set the open workbook.

Comment: Opening the workbooks works. What I am having trouble with is the rest of my code where I have hardcoded the name of the workbook (OH Detail v13). Instead of doing this, I want to be able to use xpath as the name. For example, instead of `Workbook("OH Detail v13").Select`, I want to do `Workbook(xpath).Select` but it does not seem to be working

Comment: Like they told you, avoid using `.Select` and use `Set wbOG = Workbooks(xfile & xext)` and even if you want some worksheet you could just reference the worksheet. `Set wsOG = wbOG.Sheets("Invoices")`that way you only need to use `wsOG.PivotTables("Invoices").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True`for example.